# Arduino: String join?

Tags: c++, string, arduino

I'm trying to write a `join` method for the Arduino:

```
#define ARG_DELIMITER ','

  String join(const String strs[], const int len) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      result += strs[i] + ARG_DELIMITER;
      Serial.println(result);
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
  }
```

The calling code in `loop()`:

```
const String args[3] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
Serial.println(SlaveTalk.join(args, 3));
```

This prints the following:

```
foo
foo
foo
fo
```

followed by empty strings as long as the program runs.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably more importantly, what's the `String` class/type?

Comment: @Michael - The `String` class appears to be defined [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject).

Comment: Another detail that might be of interest to people approaching this from a C++ point of view: "The Arduino language is based on C/C++" (from http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage). So it resembles, but is not exactly, C++.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
const String args[3] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

gives you the strings

```
"foo\0" "bar\0" "baz\0"
```

where the \0 is the NULL character.  So when you concat, I expect you're ending up with:

```
"foo\0bar\0baz\0"
```

The printing stops at the null which is why you see foo 3 times.  In the return statement, the length is 3 "foo" and subtracting 1 gives you "fo"

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The Arduino String class uses `strcat` for `+=`, as can be seen here: http://j.mp/dXCCrg. `strcat` overwrites the null terminator of the first buffer, and appends a new null terminator to the end: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as intended using the Arduino software version 0022 and an Arduino Duemilanove w/ ATmega 328:

```
#define ARG_DELIMITER ','

class SlaveTalkClass
{
  public:
    String join(const String strs[], const int len) {
      String result = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result += strs[i] + ARG_DELIMITER;
        Serial.println(result);
      }
      return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
    }
} SlaveTalk;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  const String args[3] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
  Serial.println(SlaveTalk.join(args, 3));
}
```

It repeatedly prints the following to the Serial Monitor:

```
foo,
foo,bar,
foo,bar,baz,
foo,bar,baz
```

Answer (score 0):

[PString](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/pstring/) is an excellent library that can concat. It has some neat features, and above all, is runtime safe.

Comment: Show how you'd use PString for the actual task, add some example code!